# General Integration and Measure by Alan J. Weir - Exercise 4 - Section 9.2

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

This is an exercise of Weir's book which can be read [here](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=P_43AAAAIAAJ&pg=PA49&lpg=PA49&dq=if+a+Lebesgue+Stieltjes+measure+is+invariant+under+translation,+then+its+a+multiple+of+Lebesgue+measure&source=bl&ots=YsCd_JuuKk&sig=wmMkMnFYopkyLkML3gIYmkqXG1E&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwihn8OSlNHdAhXFEJAKHc0VDyAQ6AEwAnoECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=if%20a%20Lebesgue%20Stieltjes%20measure%20is%20invariant%20under%20translation%2C%20then%20its%20a%20multiple%20of%20Lebesgue%20measure&f=false).

> $\textbf{4.}$ If the Lebesgue-Stieltjes measure $\mu_F$ is invariant under translations, show that $\mu_F$ is a constant multiple of Lebesgue measure. (In the one-dimensional case, show that $F$ is continuous and if $F(0) = 0$, satisfies $F(a+b) = F(a) + F(b)$ for all $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$).

I put what I thought below.

> I will follow the hint given by the author. Since $F$ is continuous on right in a point $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$, we have that, given $\eta := 2 \varepsilon > 0$, exist $\delta > 0$ such that
>
> $$x \in B(x_0, \delta) \Longrightarrow F(x) \in [F(x_0), \ F(x_0) + \eta).$$
>
> Since $\mu_F$ is invariant under translation, we have, for the same $\delta > 0$ and translating by $\frac{\eta}{2}$,
>
> $$x \in B(x_0, \delta) \Longrightarrow F(x) \in [F(x_0) - \frac{\eta}{2}, \ F(x_0) + \frac{\eta}{2} ).$$
>
> Thus, $x \in B(x_0, \delta) \Longrightarrow F(x) \in ( F(x_0) - \varepsilon, \ F(x_0) + \varepsilon )$, therefore $F$ is continuous at $x_0$.
>
> We can suppose without loss of generality that $F(0) = 0$ (if $F(0) = a \neq 0$, then it's just consider $G(x) := F(x) - a$).
>
> Given $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$, observe that
>
> $$F(a + b) - F(a) = F(b) - F(0)$$
>
> considering a translation by $a$, then
>
> $$F(a + b) = F(a) + F(b).$$

I'm stuck here. Can anyone give me a direction in order to conclude that $\mu_F$ is a multiple of Lebesgue measure? The special case when $F$ is defined on $\mathbb{R}^k$ for $k = 1$ helps me to prove the general case (for $k > 1$)?

Comment: I think you can just take $\nu =(1/c)\mu_F$ where $c=\mu_F(Q);\ Q$ the unit cube in $\mathbb R^k$. It is then enough to show that $c$ is finite and $>0$ (easy), and then show that $\nu$ agrees with the Lebesgue measure on the algebra of cubes in $\mathbb R^k$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Decompose $I=[0,1]$ in disjoint intervals, $A_i, i=1, \ldots, n$ of same Lebesgue length $Leb(A_i)=1/n$. So by translation invariance, $\alpha=\mu_F([0,1])=n\times \mu_F(A_i)$, therefore $\mu_F(A_i)=\alpha \times Leb(A_i).$  Then we have, by tranlation invariance,  $\mu_F$ and $\alpha \times Leb $ coincide in the subintervals of $I=[0,1]$, by the extension theorem they must coincide in the borelians of $[0,1]$. By translation invariance we extend this conclusion to the real line.

The general case is similar.

Comment: Why $\mu_F(A_i) = \alpha \textit{Leb}(A_i)$? I see that $\mu_F(A_i) = \frac{\mu_F([0,1])}{n}$ and $ \textit{Leb}(A_i) = \frac{1}{n}$, but I can't see how this helps me to conclude that $\mu_F(A_i) = \alpha \textit{Leb}(A_i)$.

Comment: To keep simple, choose $A_1=[0,1/n),\ldots, A_{n-1}=[(n-2)/n,(n-1)/n)$ and $A_n=[(n-1)/n,1]$.  So, $Leb(A_1)=\ldots=Leb(A_n)=1/n.$. Observe that, by Translation invariance of  $\mu_F$ and right continuity $\mu_F(A_1)=\ldots =\mu_F(A_n)$. Therefore,  $\alpha=\mu_F(I)=\sum_{i=1}^n\mu_F(A_i)$=n\times \mu_F(A_i)$.

Comment: I think that I got it. It's because $n \mu_F(A_j) = \mu_F([0,1]) = \alpha = \alpha \cdot 1 = \alpha \textit{Leb} ([0,1]) = \alpha \sum_{i = 1}^{i = n} \textit{Leb} (A_i) = \alpha n \textit{Leb} (A_j)$, then $\mu_F(A_j) = \alpha \textit{Leb} (A_j)$ for $j$ fixed, isn't it?

Comment: You're right, but I think it is more simple to divide by $n$ in both sides  in the first equality.

Comment: It's really easier. Thanks for the help! :)

Answer (score 2):

If $\mu_F$ is translation invariant, then for real $a<b$ and real $c$, 
$$
F(b)-F(a)=\mu_F\left((a,b]\right)=\mu_F\left((a+c,b+c]\right)=F(b+c)-F(a+c).
$$
Assuming, as you have shown we may, that $F(0)=0$,  the above implies (take $a=0$) that $F(b+c)=F(b)+F(c)$, at least for $b>0$. The case $b<0$ can be handled similarly. Thus $F$ is additive and continuous from the right.  The only such functions are of the form $F(x)=dx$ for real $d$. This in turn implies that $\mu_F$ is $d$ times Lebesgue measure.

Comment: why the only functions that are additive and continuous from the right are of the form $F(x) = dx$?

Comment: You could google "Cauchy's functional equation"; or proceed as follows: for addititve $F$, first show that $F(nx)=nF(x)$ for each integer $n$ and real $x$, then $F(r)=rF(1)$ for each rational $r$, then $F(x)=xF(1)$ by approximating $x$ from the right by rationals. (With more work it can be seen that it suffices for $F$ to be Lebesgue measurable.)

Comment: It's a really nice approach for this problem, but $F$ be Lebesgue measurable is not trivial now since you proved $F(x) = F(1) x$ or need fill some technical details in order to conclude that $F$ is Lebesgue measurable?